# Swap all occurrences of two strings

Tags: vim

Say, for example, I have a document with all pairs of parenthesis flipped:

> Lorem )ipsum( dolor )sit( amet

And I want to correct it to be:

> Lorem (ipsum) dolor (sit) amet

Of course I can't make the swap with two replacements; first replace all `(` with `)` and then all `)` with `(`, because then I will end up with:

> Lorem (ipsum( dolor (sit( amet

Please provide a way to do it in vim for any pair of strings.

**Update:**
Thanks *ernix* for a good answer. For those wondering what the `tr` function does:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#tr()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using vimscript:

```
:%call setline(".", tr(getline("."), "()", ")("))
```

or simply call `tr`:

```
:%!tr ')(' '()'
```

### update

If you consider about white spaces, then **Kent**'s answer is the best :)

```
%s/\(\s*\((\|)\)\s*\)/\=substitute(submatch(0),submatch(0),submatch(2)=='('?') ':' (', 'g')/g
```

Answer (score 3):

this line will do it:

```
:s/[()]/\=substitute(submatch(0),submatch(0),submatch(0)==')'?'(':')','g')/g
```

it looks lengthy because the function name `submatch(`, you can write a little function or assign the match part to a var.

with nice idea from **ernix**:

```
s/[()]/\=tr(submatch(0),')(','()')/g
```

Answer (score 1):

One trivial method:

```
%s/(/1UnIqUe1/g
%s/)/(/g
%s/1UnIqUe1/)/g
```

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for something more elegant though... :) And more importantly, I want something more robust. This wouldn't work if I happen to have the "unique" string somewhere in the text.